# Reading tweet time in R

Tags: r, twitter

I have downloaded tweets in json format.Now i want to represent the tweets creation rate with respect to time.There is a variable named 'created at' which represents when the tweet was created.I have this variable in this format:

```
Thu Apr 09 15:43:18 +0000 2015
```

I was able to read all the other things,but no idea how to read this +0000.Previously i tried reading this in R,which was a success:

```
Thu Apr 09 15:43:18 2015
```

For reading this above variable i used this following code:

```
earlier <-strptime("Thu Apr 09 15:43:18 2015","%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
```

Please help me how i can read the first code in R.

Comment: @akrun it gives this error:"character string is not in a standard unambiguous format"

Comment: I am not getting errors with R 3.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
 as.POSIXct('Thu Apr 09 15:43:18 +0000 2015', 
                        format='%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y', tz='GMT')
 #[1] "2015-04-09 15:43:18 GMT"
```

According to `?strptime`

> ‘%z’ Signed offset in hours and minutes from UTC, so ‘-0800’ is 8
>             hours behind UTC. Values up to ‘+1400’ are accepted as from R
>             3.1.1: previous versions only accepted up to ‘+1200’.
>             (Standard only for output.)